# Convert image pixels into featureCollection without aggregate equal pixels in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, reducers

I'm working with Google Earth Engine. I need to convert the image pixels into a featureCollection. I'm using the `reduceToVectors()` function however, this function combines the pixels with the same value into a single polygon.

How can I avoid this aggregation?

Script here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/67d3858ab1cd2ee443054e657eb77aed

```
// var geometry --> draw your own geometry
var s2Col = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
    .filter(ee.Filter.inList('MGRS_TILE', ['30SYJ']))
    .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 75)
    .filterDate('2019-05-10', '2019-05-12');

var s2Image = s2Col.first();

var imageClip = s2Image.clip(geometry).select('B4');

var imagePixCol = imageClip.reduceToVectors({scale:10});
print(imagePixCol);

Map.addLayer(imagePixCol);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `image.sample()` for this.

But why are you converting pixels to a featureCollection in the first place.  (This is often a sign you're doing something improper).

Comment: The reason to convert the pixels into a featureCollection of polygons is that I need to calculate the percentage of each pixel covered by a polygon (in my case an agricultural parcel). This allows me to filter full pixels inside a parcel, or pixels covered >75%, >50%, etc. This functionality is implemented in some software packages such as the R package `exactextractr`. I take this opportunity to pass on to you the suggestion to implement this new feature in GEE.

Comment: You don't need to convert to vector to do that, you can do it entirely in raster space (and much faster), by rasterizing the polygon.  You'll just need to do the summation at a much higher resolution.